# Iterate/fetch data from camel exchange into java object

Tags: java, apache-camel

In the project flow i am getting the data in form of json collection in apache camel exchange and to process it further i need to transform it in java object

```
try{

        List<RespModel> records = (List<RespModel>) exchange.getIn().getBody(RespModel.class);

        System.out.println(records.size());

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("NO LUCK "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

But i am getting records as null.
Could you please help me to transform this ?

exchange data is as below -

````
      "identifier": {
          "domain": "transport",
          "id": "123",
          "version": 1
      },
      "record": "NEW",
      "payload": {
          "pesonalDetails" : {
          "name" : "bla bla bla"
          "dob" : 
          },
          "reason" :
          
      }
},{
      "identifier": {
          "domain": "transport",
          "id": "123",
          "version": 1
      },
      "record": "NEW",
      "payload": {
          "pesonalDetails" : {
          "name" : "bla bla bla"
          "dob" : 
          },
          "reason" :
          
      }]```

I am getting null here, how can i achieve this ? pls reply if you know. Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer finally -

```
String result = IOUtils.toString((InputStream) exchange.getIn().getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        List<RespModel> = new ObjectMapper().readValue(result,
                new TypeReference<List<RespModel>>() {
                });
```